# How to run a particular method only on success of another method?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have been able to run this absolutely fine :

```
public void daliytest() {

        me.login();

        czz.createzoo();


        czz.addanimals();


        me.logout();

    }
```

Now I want something like this :

```
public void daliytest() {

        me.login();

        czz.createzoo();

        if (czz.createzoo.isSuccess){
        czz.addanimals();
            }

        me.logout();

    }
```

Please excuse me (a beginner) if I am asking a very basic question related to java.
Thanks

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Look for "method return values" in your Java textbook.

Comment: I think you want something an [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either returns a boolean in `createzoo()` to indicate the success or throw an `Exception` when something go wrong.

If you choose to work with a boolean :

```
if(czz.createzoo()) {
    czz.addanimals();
}
```

Here is an example of a method that returns a boolean upon success :

```
public boolean createzoo() {
    if(name != null) {
        this.zoo = new Zoo(name);
        return true; // Success
    } else {
        return false; // Failure
    }
}
```

If you choose to work with exceptions :

```
try {
    czz.createzoo();
    czz.addanimals();
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since createzoo() may throw an exception, you have to use a try/catch block to handle the exception. If an exception is thrown by `createzoo()`, the code will jump to the catch block and `addanimals()` will not be executed.

Here is an example of a method that throws an exception when something goes wrong :

```
public void createzoo() {
    if(name != null) {
        this.zoo = new Zoo(name);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No name has been set for the zoo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow..it worked...!!. I was interested in boolean , that worked too.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using normal code, then you can check the return value of the first method and decide whether you want to call the second method or not

or

If you are using the `Junit`, you can invoke the other method depending on the assert result you put in. Something like

```
// in first method
if (assertTrue(condition)) {

//call second method

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make czz.createzoo() to return a **boolean**, returning true if it was successful, then execute an if:

```
public void daliytest() {

    me.login();

    boolean success = czz.createzoo();

    if (success){
        czz.addanimals();
    }

    me.logout();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return true or false in `czz.createzoo();` and use it in if condition

```
if(czz.createzoo()){
//Success.
}
else{
//Failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have your createZoo method to return true of zoo is successfully created, otherwise false. Then you can write like below

```
public void daliytest() {

    me.login();


    if (czz.createzoo()){
    czz.addanimals();
        }

    me.logout();

}
```